# Can I use HAXM on a Linux inside VMWare?

Tags: android, linux, vmware, haxm

I have VMWare installed on Windows 7. In VMWare, I have an Ubuntu Machine with the environment to develop Android applications. My machine has an i7 processor. For the VM, I assigned two processors with two cores and enabled Vt-x. I already followed successfully all the steps in https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/03/12/how-to-start-intel-hardware-assisted-virtualization-hypervisor-on-linux-to-speed-up-intel-android-x86-emulator, but when I start the emulator I can't notice any improvement (I'm not getting the expected confirmation that HAXM is enabled when I start the emulator).

I installed HAXM on Windows and it works just fine but I really need to use Linux for my development environment.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Comment: Android Development works great on Windows 7. I assume there's some other non-standard part of your development process that requires Linux?

Comment: It works great but I was reading that the performance is much better on Linux (that's why I was using a VM). Finally I decided to install Ubuntu on my machine and install HAXM on it. The difference in performance is real. On Linux, the emulator is, at least, twice as fast it is on Windows. Maybe Linux is not as easy as Windows, but is definitely faster (at least for development purposes).

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely possible now in 2017.

You need:

1. An Intel CPU (HAXM is Intel only)
2. Enable VT-x in the BIOS
3. Enable VT-x in the VMWare Host settings for the CPU and MMU virtualization
4. Enable "Expose hardware assisted virtualization to the guest operating system"
5. (Windows Server only) Disable Hyper-V
6. A version of VMWare that supports exposing the HV inside the guest OS.
7. Install HAXM on the guest OS

See:
https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970

With these steps, I was able to start a HAXM accelerated x86_64 Android VM inside a Windows 2012 guest OS under ESXi 6.0.

Note: I had to use a software-based GPU to get the VM to start, but I don't have a capable graphics card in the server, so that may be related to VM configuration/limitations and/or the underlying hardware capabilities of my server.

Answer (score 1):

I kept reading about it and discovered that is not possible to enable HAXM on a virtual machine (it would be like virtualize over virtualized). HAXM requires access to the "real" hardware.